# Silence my Pentax k1000

Tags: pentax, sound

I just bought my first camera. A Pentax k1000. I really want to eliminate my shutter sound or just the sound of the mirror slapping. What do you suggest

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to silence the Pentax K1000 mirror. The K1000 does not have an option for [mirror lock-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_lock-up). You would want to look at a SLR that has mirror lock-up as an option or for a camera that does not have a mirror.

Comment: In low-light, lock-up could be simulated using bulb mode and some external object acting as shutter. But mirror lock-up would not really eliminate the sound, just change its timing. There is an option though, putting the camera inside a [sound blimp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_blimp).